# What is the difference between the External and the Internal clock rate in reference to the RAM ?

Tags: memory

I'm reading an article on the [DDR2 Memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR2_SDRAM), and now I'm totally confused.  What does this line means

> "Since the DDR2 internal clock runs at half the DDR external clock
>   rate, DDR2 memory operating at the same external data bus clock rate
>   as DDR results in DDR2 being able to provide the same bandwidth but
>   with higher latency."

- What is the difference between Internal and External clock rate in
  reference to the RAM?
- What is I/O clock rate, Memory clock rate and Bus clock rate ?

---

This is a [comparison  chart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_device_bandwidths) of different types of RAM from the Wikipedia .

Module type    ChipType    Clock speed    Bus speed 
   Transfer rate (byte/s)

PC2-6400             DDR2-800         400MHz
            800 MT/s       06.4GB/s

PC3-6400           DDR3-800       400MHz
         800 MT/s       06.4 GB/s

---

How can be the transfer rate of DDR2 and DDR3 RAM with the same clock speed of 400 MHz are same ?

Answer (score 0):

DDR,DDR2 and DDR3 memories follow the DDRxxx/PCyyyy classification.

xxx indicates the maximum  clock speed the memory chips support.eg DDR400 memories work at 400 MHz at the most,DDR2-800 can work up to 800 MHz and DDR3-1333 can work up to 1,333MHz.Though this is not thr real clock speed of the memory.The real clock of DDR,DDR2, and DDR3 memories if half of the labeled clock speed.Therefore DDR400 memories work at 200 MHz,DDR2-800 memories at 400 MHZ.

yyyy number indicates the maximum transfer rate that the memory reaches in MB/s.

The bus clock rate is the actual speed of ur FSB(The FSB connects the processor (CPU) in your computer to the system memory)

Answer (score 0):

The various generations of DDR RAM have an internal datapath that transfers data from a small capacitor array to the internal I/O buffer. The internal clock rate is the frequency needed to match the external clock rate. So DDR types with larger data-depth require less internal transfers per second to match the external speed.

The above is a quick summary of info at [hardwaresecrets.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20171108133311/http://www.hardwaresecrets.com/everything-you-need-to-know-about-ddr-ddr2-and-ddr3-memories/5/) The image below is also from there.

[image]

Disregarding latency differences the above memory chips will have equal performance, but lower internal frequency chips have less power consumption.